# Pulling Google Sheets as data source for Google Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm attempting to pull data from Google Sheets and use it as a source for my [Gantt chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#loading). I've followed the example in the Google Charts documentation for [pulling Sheets data for a columnchart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#gid), but not sure if more customization is necessary.

I'm not as familiar with Javascript, so not sure what is triggering the error. Here is the code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qo7m7se/).

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function daystoMilliseconds(days) {
  return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}

function drawGID() {
  var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H');

  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f0wxDrEfptRKCRY5pQPu6Dc_ue_tIX_ja5pQO3vXjOY/edit#gid=0&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
  query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
}

function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }}

function drawChart() {

  var otherData = response.getDataTable();

  var options = {
    height: 275,
    gantt: {
      defaultStartDateMillis: new Date(2015, 3, 28)
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(otherData, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first, the `callback` should be --> `drawGID`

instead of --> `drawChart`

---

next, notice the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#data-format) for a Gantt chart

both the `'Start'` and `'End'` dates are required and cannot be blank,
as in the spreadsheet

---

see following working snippet...

a new data table is built, using the data from the spreadsheet (`otherData`),
using the `'Duration'` column to fill in the the dates

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawGID,
  packages: ['gantt']
});

function drawGID() {
  var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H');

  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f0wxDrEfptRKCRY5pQPu6Dc_ue_tIX_ja5pQO3vXjOY/edit#gid=0&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
  query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
}

function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var otherData = response.getDataTable();
  var ganttData = new google.visualization.DataTable({cols: [
    {type: 'string', label: 'Task Id'},
    {type: 'string', label: 'Task Name'},
    {type: 'string', label: 'Resource'},
    {type: 'date', label: 'Start'},
    {type: 'date', label: 'End'},
    {type: 'number', label: 'Duration'},
    {type: 'number', label: '% Complete'},
    {type: 'string', label: 'Dependencies'}
  ]});

  var duration = 0;
  var startDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1);
  var endDate;
  for (var i = 0; i < otherData.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    startDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + duration);
    duration += otherData.getValue(i, 5);
    endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + duration);
    ganttData.addRow([
      otherData.getValue(i, 0),
      otherData.getValue(i, 1),
      otherData.getValue(i, 2),
      startDate,
      endDate,
      otherData.getValue(i, 5),
      parseFloat(otherData.getValue(i, 6)),
      otherData.getValue(i, 7)
    ]);
  }

  var options = {
    height: 275,
    gantt: {
      defaultStartDateMillis: new Date(2015, 3, 28)
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(ganttData, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following Google project allows you to view a Google Spreadsheet as a Gantt Chart:
https://github.com/google/ezgantt

[image]